remix-run (node.js) drizzle-orm multi-tenancy
So I have a main database where I store users, tenants, contstants etc. And multiple schemas to store tenant data separately. I'm using remix.
Case 1: If I don't store the connection in memory, it will cause "too many connections" error.
Case 2: If I store connections in memory, the connection will eventualy time out and it will cause the app to crash.
So I came out with a solution like below but something tells me thats not the best practice to use in prod.
If someone with experience could tell me if I'm going the right direction or way off I'd really appreciate.
export const masterDbOptions = {
  host: zenv.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: zenv.DATABASE_PORT,
  user: zenv.DATABASE_USER,
  password: zenv.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: zenv.DATABASE_NAME,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  enableKeepAlive: true,
} satisfies mysql2.ConnectionOptions;

//* _______ master db _______ */
/* we create a connection to the master db synchronously */
const main = mysql2.createConnection({ ...masterDbOptions });
export const db = drizzle(main, { schema, mode: 'default' });

/* function to create a connection to a tenant db asynchronously */
const createConn = async (db: string) => await mysql2promise.createConnection({ ...masterDbOptions, database: db });

/* we store the tenant connections in memory so that we can reuse them */
let tenantConnections: { [key: string]: Awaited<Promise<mysql2promise.Connection>> } = {};

const resumeConn = async (tenantName: string) => {
  /* we want to end the connection if it exists
    then create a new connection and store it in the tenantConnections object
    so that we can reuse it until db timeout
  */
  tenantConnections[tenantName]?.end();
  tenantConnections[tenantName] = await createConn(`tenant_${tenantName}`)
    .then((conn) => conn)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      throw new Error('Error creating tenant connection');
    });

  return drizzle(tenantConnections[tenantName], {
    schema: tenancySchema,
    mode: 'default',
  });
};

//* _______ tenant db _______ */
export const tdb = async (
  request: Request,
  {
    permissions,
  }: {
    permissions?: UserPermissions[];
  } = {},
) => {
  const { user, tenant } = await authenticate(request, {
    permissions,
  });

  const db = await resumeConn(tenant);

  type DB = typeof db & { ctx: { user: typeof user.username } };

  (db as DB).ctx = { user: user.username };

  return db as DB;
};

Usage example;
const query = await tdb(request, {
    permissions: [UserPermissions.GetCustomers],
  }).then((db) =>
    db.query.customers.findFirst({
      where: eq(customers.id, Number(params.id)),
    }),
  );

EDIT:
Maybe something like that?
const resumeConn = async (tenantName: string) => {
  /* we want to end the connection if it exists
    then create a new connection and store it in the tenantConnections object
    so that we can reuse it until db timeout
  */
  const ping = await tenantConnections[tenantName]
    ?.ping()
    .then(() => true)
    .catch(() => false);

  if (!ping) {
    // tenantConnections[tenantName]?.end();
    tenantConnections[tenantName] = await createConn(`tenant_${tenantName}`)
      .then((conn) => conn)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error('Error creating tenant connection');
      });
  }

  return drizzle(tenantConnections[tenantName], {
    schema: tenancySchema,
    mode: 'default',
  });
};

